# repartition HD Linux Mint

Tags: partition, hard-disk

Here is what have now.

[image]

As you see, I'm running out space on /dev/sda6.I'm not sure how to move partitions around to gain space. I surly don't want to mess up.

Comment: That drive looks like it has a Windows 7-style MBR 'legacy' partition table, not a UEFI type Windows 10-style GPT partition table.  It's important to find where you boot from. Please run sudo parted -l and copy the result, then click edit and paste the result into your question. Please do not click on [Add Comment] for when comments pile up, old comments get pushed off the screen. We should have all the info needed in the Question to provide a complete answer.

Comment: Is it your intent to make this a Mint-only system? Or, do you have plans for that un-allocated space before sda2? Would it be satisfactory to create a new partition in the allocated space and put whatever's in sda7 there, then expand sda6 to take up the space formerly used by sda5, sda6, and sda7 combined? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an immediate answer to solve the problem while you find where you boot from, as requested above.

Firstly, back up your important data.

Next, read https://askubuntu.com/questions/640497/moving-the-boot-partition.

Then, you will need to boot from an external drive, such as a [LiveUSB Flash Drive](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html), like the one you probably used to install Mint. Then, you can use [gparted](https://gparted.org/) to repartition **sda**.

If you are using Mint 18 or above, the penalty for using a swap file instead of a swap partition is long since solved, so you can eliminate the swap partition and instead [create a swap file](https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space) in **sda7** once partitioning is completed.  This gets you another 5.6GB right away while I research the possibilities of problems in moving all partitions. You would so this with three commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/swapfile bs=2048 count=2097152
```

**/path/to/** *swapfile* is the name and location of the swap file, and the count of **2097152** is the size in kilobytes (i.e., 2GB). In Linux, rarely do you need a swap space (be it partition or file) larger than your RAM, and you can monitor your swap space and adjust it much more easily when you have a swap file.

Prepare that swap file with [mkswap](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkswap) just as you would a partition, but this time use the swap file name:

```
mkswap /path/to/swapfile
```

Then mount it with the [swapon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/swapon.2.html) command:

```
swapon /path/to/swapfile
```

You can also safely take space from sda7 and add it to sda6 after removing the swap partition. I would do it in this order:

A) Remove **swap** partition (**sda5**)
B) Shrink **sda7**
C) Add the space gained to **sda6**
D) Commit and make changes
E) Shut down, remove LiveUSB, boot from internat drive.